# Как уменьшить отступ текста в spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, padding

Spinner занимает слишком много места. Нашел как уменьшить размер шрифта. Но добавляется большой отступ от стрелки выпадающего списка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать этот отступ?

Comment: Отступ задает фон. Фоном является 9-patch изображение. Задайте ему свой фон, и отступы уберутся.

Comment: @metalurgus Если такая длина не задана хардкорно для виджета (или условиями разметки), то думаю, в данном случае отступ связан с длиной самого большого слова в выпадающем списке и так просто эту проблему не решить, скорее всего - вообще не решить.

Comment: @metalurgus задал на фон xml c рамкой потом просто фон, не помогло. очевидно отступ действительно зависит от самого большого слова в списке